# DB schema to store billion e-mails

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to develop an application where users can import their e-mails into and search their imported e-mails. As this will probably be used by many users (easily 10k+) the database design is critical. With these numbers of users the database will probably need to be able to hold over a billion rows (e-mails).

The application will need to be able to quickly return records after a search query is posted on the application. The database will be heavily searched and I would like some help on creating the database table(s) for creating an efficient db schema. I have a lot experience with MySQL myself but I've read somewhere I shouldn't go that way and go look for MongoDB or something? Is the difference so big or is there any way I can still go with MySQL?

- from
- to
- subject
- date (range)
- attachments (names & types only)
- message contents
- (optional) mailbox / folder structure

These are the searchable fields, of course all e-mails will have an extra two "columns" for the unique id and the user_id. I've found several db schemas of e-mail but I can't find any documentation of a schema that will work with over a billion rows.

Comment: Is that a thousand million, or a million million? `:)`. If you _really_ might get to this level, get an external service to do it - I suspect there must be an email storage solution you can interact with using APIs. That said, be realistic about what you need: could this be premature optimisation?

Comment: 1,000,000,000+ e-mails stored. The idea is to run this on the amazon cloud (scalable). My idea is to store the e-mails in a package into the S3 storage after inserting the important (searchable) fields into the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You would be best off starting simple with your proposed table definition and going from there - if the site does get near a billion records then if needed you can move it to amazon servers or another cloud host which (should) allow the table to the partioned.

MySQL can handle a fair amount of data, assuming you are not on a shared host with restrictions.

So, start simple, dont optimise a problem that doesnt exist yet, and see how it goes.

Comment: good point, i would add that let create a separate table for each customer - thus you wouldnt have one uber-table to search in and it will not take forever to find results.

Comment: @ulkas If you use sharding correctly it will take only a couple of ms to query the table